# Add a custom view to main view programatically in android

Tags: android, android-view

I have two views in an Fragment. First view is main view declared in onCreateView() named as weather.xml and second view is a view which is in project res/layout/weather_column.xml.

I want to add weather_column.xml to weather.xml programatically using a loop.

Finally, it should be like ...

[image]

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams;

public class WeatherFragment2 extends Fragment {

private static final String TAG = WeatherFragment2.class.getSimpleName();
LinearLayout bottemLL;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
LayoutParams params ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    params = new LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,      
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
    );

    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.weather, container, false);

    layoutInflater = inflater;
    LinearLayout bottemLL = (LinearLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.bottem_ll);

    addView(bottemLL);


    return v;
}

private void addView(LinearLayout bottemLL2) {
    View v ;

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        Log.e(TAG, "i=========="+i);

        v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_column, null);
        bottemLL2.addView(v, params);
    }
}

}
```

But i am able to add view only once after doing loop.

Please help me on this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code what you posted indeed adds 6 different view to your LinearLayout. So that part should be fine.

I guess the problem is that they too big, so they cant fit in the same container. Try to modify the underlying XML-s.

Could you send your layout files?

Comment: Yes, The child is too big. Thanks kupsef

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are adding always the same view, you should make a new View inside the loop, and inflate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
private void addView(LinearLayout bottemLL2) 
{
    View v ;
    v = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.weather_column, null);

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) 
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "i=========="+i);
        bottemLL2.addView(v, params);
    }
}
```

Comment: getting an error. This child has already parent must remove before adding the view on second loop